# Chrome and fonts issues

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

This is an issue I noticed in an application that is using icon fonts through all fonts are having issues.  Basically the issue is that when I leave the application in a background tab for awhile, sometimes when I come back the fonts get reset to something (most but not all icon fonts show up as squares) and when I move my mouse over the screen, the fonts are switched back to what they should be.

I have made a video to show the issue:

https://vimeo.com/86414508

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe screenshots would be better than a video, I have *"This video can’t be played with your current setup."*. At least as complement ?

Comment: save your font files on you site ! Hope that help

Comment: Does this happen in other browsers?

Comment: @l2aelba I have the same problem even while I serve the font myself.

Comment: So dup : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21577513/622813 ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a known issue in Chrome as it's been answered here :

[Icon-font sporadically shows up as squares and back to icon on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441353/icon-font-sporadically-shows-up-as-squares-and-back-to-icon-on-hover?lq=1)

It's a little annoying but I guess it won't be too much of a problem since they come back when you hover the page again and I'm sure it'll be fixed in the next versions of Chrome.