# Chrome/Win: Inconsistent rendering results after a page refresh

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm writing my pixel-perfect jquery plugin to align menu items in a brick-wall way and I'm struggling with text rendering engine differences that render a given string with different widths between Chrome and IE/FF. This pushes me to search for various css techniques and tricks (such as `text-rendering`, `-webkit-font-kerning`) and I still have... inconsistent results.

The key of the randomness is that after **a longer time** of page inactivity (during which I search the web), refreshing it renders the text as expected, then - the subsequent refreshes, but **in a close succession**, render the text a bit wider, which lays out the menu in a different way, taking 3 rows instead of 2.

This occurs both when I use Google Fonts and system Arial.

The algorithm is done and working OK, so my question is not about fixing javascript or css, rather about how I could prevent the randomness from occurring. Is there any `<meta>` tag that I could use to get consistent results, or something?

Comment: This sounds very similar to other questions asked here about Chrome, fonts and refreshing after a some time. Apparently there's a bug in Chrome which causes it to purge memory it thinks it doesn't need when it's idle. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21441353/1016716) for instance.

Comment: OK, thanks, sometimes it's just good to know there's nothing you can do, but wait for a fix...